# flink: job won't run with higher taskmanager.heap.mb

Tags: java, apache-flink

Simple job: `kafka->flatmap->reduce->map`.

Job runs ok with default value for **taskmanager.heap.mb** (512Mb). According to the [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/setup/config.html#configuring-taskmanager-processing-slots): `this value should be as large as possible`. Since the machine in question has 96Gb of RAM I set this to 75000 (arbitrary value).

Starting job gives this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.   
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$5.apply$mcV$sp(JobManager.scala:563)   
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$5.apply(JobManager.scala:509)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$5.apply(JobManager.scala:509)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:401)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: Not enough free slots available to run the job. You can decrease the operator parallelism or increase the number of slots per TaskManager in the configuration. Task to schedule: < Attempt #0 (Source: Custom Source (1/1)) @ (unassigned) - [SCHEDULED] > with groupID < 95b239d1777b2baf728645df9a1c4232 > in sharing group < SlotSharingGroup [772c9ff1cf0b6cb3a361e3352f75fcee, d4f856f13654f424d7c49d0f00f6ecca, 81bb8c4310faefe32f97ebd6baa4c04f, 95b239d1777b2baf728645df9a1c4232] >. Resources available to scheduler: Number of instances=0, total number of slots=0, available slots=0
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.Scheduler.scheduleTask(Scheduler.java:255)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.Scheduler.scheduleImmediately(Scheduler.java:131)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.scheduleForExecution(Execution.java:298)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionVertex.scheduleForExecution(ExecutionVertex.java:458)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionJobVertex.scheduleAll(ExecutionJobVertex.java:322)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph.scheduleForExecution(ExecutionGraph.java:686)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$org$apache$flink$runtime$jobmanager$JobManager$$submitJob$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobManager.scala:982)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$org$apache$flink$runtime$jobmanager$JobManager$$submitJob$1.apply(JobManager.scala:962)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$org$apache$flink$runtime$jobmanager$JobManager$$submitJob$1.apply(JobManager.scala:962)
... 8 more
```

Restore the default value (512) to this parameter and the job runs ok. At 5000 it works -> at 10000 it doesn't.

What did I miss?

---

Edit:  This is more hit-n-miss than I thought. Setting the value to 50000 and resubmitting gives success.  In every test, the cluster is stopped and restarted.

Comment: Did you check in the JobManager web-interface whether all your TaskManagers connected? With very large amounts of RAM it could take a while for them to come up since they allocate almost all the ram you give to them as byte[] arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are probably experiencing is submitting a job before the workers have registered at the master.

A 5GB JVM heap is initialized fast, and the TaskManager can register almost immediately. For a 70GB heap, the JVM takes a while to initialize and boot. Consequently, the worker registers later, and the job cannot be executed when you submit it, due to a lack of workers.

That is also the reason why it works once you re-submit the job.

JVMs are initialized faster, if you start the cluster in "streaming" mode (standalone via start-cluster-streaming.sh), because then at least Flink's internal memory is initialized lazily.

Comment: One way to check this is the web dashboard, where it shows how many TaskManagers are registered. If you want to automate this, the REST monitoring API supports requests for that, such as "/overview". For details, see: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/internals/monitoring_rest_api.html